# python: can improt package from command line but not from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, package, tabula-py

I've gotten a problem where I'm trying to import the tabula package into jupyter notebooks.  I activated my conda virtual environment, pip installed tabula-py, and ran `pip freeze`.  It confirmed that tabula-py was installed.

```
certifi==2021.5.30
distro==1.6.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
greenlet==1.1.0
importlib-metadata==4.6.1
keyring==23.0.1
numpy==1.21.1
openpyxl==3.0.7
pandas==1.3.0
pyodbc==4.0.31
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.1
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.21
tabula-py==2.3.0
wincertstore==0.2
XlsxWriter==1.4.4
zipp==3.5.0
```

While my virtual environment was active, I tested out importing the tabula package from the command line (`import tabula`).  Everything works!  I run `exit()` to get out of the python instance, then run `jupyter notebook` to bring up a jupyter notebook.  (still in my virtual environment)

However, in jupyter my import statement no longer works, even though i didn't change anything.  I run `help('modules')` within jupyter, and now tabula doesn't exist in my list of packages???? I'm not sure why it isn't working.  I have the Java PATH set, and it works fine everywhere except jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Try run this command:

`!pip install tabula`

After this try to import it and see if it works

Comment: After running that, I get an error saying it is already installed.

Requirement already satisfied: tabula-py in c:\users\agray\anaconda3\envs\pyvenv\lib\site-packages (2.3.0)

Comment: but that's not an error, it's just saying that you allready have the package installed, sorry man but that's all that i could do for you